# How to run a t test using difference scores of means in R?

Tags: r, mean

Sorry if this is a silly question, I'm sure there's an easy solution!
I'm attempting to run some post hoc follow up t-tests with data using RT values to congruent and incongruent cues, but also a condition where the cue was something you were supposed to remember, or was something for a partner to remember or no one to remember

I want to run a t test where I compare between memory conditions using the difference between the means of the participants RT to congruent and incongruent cues.

Issues: the data isn't suitable to convert to wide format - this means that I can't add a new column that is this difference of means variable (because it has far less rows than my data) and run the t test using that.

Please help!